# jade extends layout and if statement

Tags: node.js, express, pug

hi and sorry for my english.

I've a very simple "layout.jade"

```
!!! 5
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
```

and a very simple "index.jade"

```
extends layout

block content
     - if (session) {
          p Welcome
     - } else {
          p Login
      -}
```

With this code i've got a blank page.

Now if i remove `extends layout` from my "index.jade" and i put the code directly in "index.jade" everything works fine, that is to say my conditional statement give me `<p>Welcome</p>` or `<p>Login</p>` no blank page any more.

I'm new to nodejs and my problem may be evident for many of you ;)

Thanks!

Comment: jade directly supports `if` and `else`. Don't use the `-` code operator for that. just `if session`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a leading whitespace mismatch, which is a no-no in significant whitespace languages like jade. Also `if` and `else` are directly supported in jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  if session
    p Welcome
  else
    p Login
```

Comment: Ok, to be sure i've downloaded a tut about jade. The problem in my files is that i'm using tab and not space. Is there a way to use tab instead of space ? With space everything is ok, but i like tab ;)

Comment: No more problems with that. In Sublime Text i modified the tab settings with "indent using space". Have a nice day :)